# Plot multiple series of data into a single bagplot with R

Tags: r, visualization, boxplot, bagplot

Let's condsider the [bagplot example](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/aplpack/docs/bagplot) as included in the aplpack library in R. A bagplot is a bivariate generalisation of a boxplot and therefore gives insight in the distribution of data points in both axes.

Example of a bagplot:
[image: car data bagplot]

Code for the example:

```
  # example of Rousseeuw et al., see R-package rpart
  cardata <- structure(as.integer( c(2560,2345,1845,2260,2440,
   2285, 2275, 2350, 2295, 1900, 2390, 2075, 2330, 3320, 2885,
   3310, 2695, 2170, 2710, 2775, 2840, 2485, 2670, 2640, 2655,
   3065, 2750, 2920, 2780, 2745, 3110, 2920, 2645, 2575, 2935,
   2920, 2985, 3265, 2880, 2975, 3450, 3145, 3190, 3610, 2885,
   3480, 3200, 2765, 3220, 3480, 3325, 3855, 3850, 3195, 3735,
   3665, 3735, 3415, 3185, 3690, 97, 114, 81, 91, 113, 97, 97,
   98, 109, 73, 97, 89, 109, 305, 153, 302, 133, 97, 125, 146,
   107, 109, 121, 151, 133, 181, 141, 132, 133, 122, 181, 146,
   151, 116, 135, 122, 141, 163, 151, 153, 202, 180, 182, 232,
   143, 180, 180, 151, 189, 180, 231, 305, 302, 151, 202, 182,
   181, 143, 146, 146)), .Dim = as.integer(c(60, 2)), 
   .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Weight", "Disp.")))
  bagplot(cardata,factor=3,show.baghull=TRUE,
    show.loophull=TRUE,precision=1,dkmethod=2)
  title("car data Chambers/Hastie 1992")
  # points of y=x*x
  bagplot(x=1:30,y=(1:30)^2,verbose=FALSE,dkmethod=2)
```

The bagplot of aplpack seems to only support plotting a "bag" for a single data series. Even more interesting would be to plot two (or three) data series within a single bagplot, where visually comparing the "bags" of the data series gives insight in the differences in the data distributions of the data series. Does anyone know if (and if so, how) this can be done in R?

Comment: `bagplot` has an add parameter. This is have been something you could have answered by a more careful reading the help page.

Comment: Also consider faceting it, via `par('mfrow')`, `par('mfcol')`, `layout()`, or `par('fig')`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we modify some of the `aplpack::bagplot` code we can make a new geom for ggplot2. Then we can compare groups within a dataset in the usual ggplot2 ways. Here's one example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, 
                 colour = Species, fill = Species)) +
       geom_bag() +
       theme_minimal()
```

[image]

and we can show the points with the bagplot:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, 
                     colour = Species, fill = Species)) +
           geom_bag() +
           geom_point() + 
           theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Here's the code for the `geom_bag` and modified  `aplpack::bagplot` function: https://gist.github.com/benmarwick/00772ccea2dd0b0f1745

Comment: What is the best way to go about installing this in R?

Comment: @ElijahRockers I added some code to the gist to show how to load the functions so you can use them locally: https://gist.github.com/benmarwick/00772ccea2dd0b0f1745#file-002_bag_demo-r-L1