# Double box plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to describe the distributions of two variables using box plots spanning both the x and y axes.

The site [linked here](https://tomizonor.wordpress.com/2013/03/15/double-box-plot/) has some nice examples (below) and it has package using base plot - [boxplotdbl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boxplotdbl/index.html).

I was wondering if a similar plot was possible in `ggplot2`. Using the figure below as an example and the `iris` data, how can I plot the box plot of `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width` and color by `Species`?

[image]

I was surprised to see that following code is close, but would like the whiskers, rather than the box, to be extended along the x-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Species), alpha = 0.3) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I edited the question to make it more specific to  `ggplot`.

Comment: No problem, I would add the link to CRAN, too, for future readers. Why not use base plot?

Comment: You could use bag-plots (2d box-plots), which i also think look better. Worth reading this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501282/plot-multiple-series-of-data-into-a-single-bagplot-with-r

Comment: your code `+ coord_flip()`

Comment: @zx8754 I have a number of different groups (~10) and the additional functionality of `ggplot` including `facet_wrap` is needed to help the clarity of my real data.

Comment: @B.Davis not sure how you get that 2D box plot, I use the same code ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Species), alpha = 0.3) +
  theme_bw() and I don't get overlapping boxplots

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate the relevant numbers required by each boxplot, & construct the 2-dimensional boxplots using different geoms.

**Step 1**. Plot each dimension's boxplot separately:

```
plot.x <- ggplot(iris) + geom_boxplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length))
plot.y <- ggplot(iris) + geom_boxplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Width))

grid.arrange(plot.x, plot.y, ncol=2) # visual verification of the boxplots
```

[image: side by side boxplots]

**Step 2**. Obtain the calculated boxplot values (including outliers) in 1 data frame:

```
plot.x <- layer_data(plot.x)[,1:6]
plot.y <- layer_data(plot.y)[,1:6]
colnames(plot.x) <- paste0("x.", gsub("y", "", colnames(plot.x)))
colnames(plot.y) <- paste0("y.", gsub("y", "", colnames(plot.y)))
df <- cbind(plot.x, plot.y); rm(plot.x, plot.y)
df$category <- sort(unique(iris$Species))

> df
  x.min x.lower x.middle x.upper x.max x.outliers y.min y.lower
1   4.3   4.800      5.0     5.2   5.8              2.9   3.200
2   4.9   5.600      5.9     6.3   7.0              2.0   2.525
3   5.6   6.225      6.5     6.9   7.9        4.9   2.5   2.800
  y.middle y.upper y.max    y.outliers   category
1      3.4   3.675   4.2      4.4, 2.3     setosa
2      2.8   3.000   3.4               versicolor
3      3.0   3.175   3.6 3.8, 2.2, 3.8  virginica
```

Step 3. Create a separate data frame for outliers:

```
df.outliers <- df %>%
  select(category, x.middle, x.outliers, y.middle, y.outliers) %>%
  data.table::data.table()
df.outliers <- df.outliers[, list(x.outliers = unlist(x.outliers), y.outliers = unlist(y.outliers)), 
                           by = list(category, x.middle, y.middle)]

> df.outliers
    category x.middle y.middle x.outliers y.outliers
1:    setosa      5.0      3.4         NA        4.4
2:    setosa      5.0      3.4         NA        2.3
3: virginica      6.5      3.0        4.9        3.8
4: virginica      6.5      3.0        4.9        2.2
5: virginica      6.5      3.0        4.9        3.8
```

**Step 4**. Putting it all together in one plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill = category, color = category)) +

  # 2D box defined by the Q1 & Q3 values in each dimension, with outline
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = x.lower, xmax = x.upper, ymin = y.lower, ymax = y.upper), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = x.lower, xmax = x.upper, ymin = y.lower, ymax = y.upper), 
            color = "black", fill = NA) +

  # whiskers for x-axis dimension with ends
  geom_segment(aes(x = x.min, y = y.middle, xend = x.max, yend = y.middle)) + #whiskers
  geom_segment(aes(x = x.min, y = y.lower, xend = x.min, yend = y.upper)) + #lower end
  geom_segment(aes(x = x.max, y = y.lower, xend = x.max, yend = y.upper)) + #upper end

  # whiskers for y-axis dimension with ends
  geom_segment(aes(x = x.middle, y = y.min, xend = x.middle, yend = y.max)) + #whiskers
  geom_segment(aes(x = x.lower, y = y.min, xend = x.upper, yend = y.min)) + #lower end
  geom_segment(aes(x = x.lower, y = y.max, xend = x.upper, yend = y.max)) + #upper end

  # outliers
  geom_point(data = df.outliers, aes(x = x.outliers, y = y.middle), size = 3, shape = 1) + # x-direction
  geom_point(data = df.outliers, aes(x = x.middle, y = y.outliers), size = 3, shape = 1) + # y-direction

  xlab("Sepal.Length") + ylab("Sepal.Width") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(4, 8), ylim = c(2, 4.5)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: 2D boxplot]

We can visually verify that the 2D boxplots are reasonable, by comparing it with a scatter plot of the original dataset on the same two dimensions:

```
# p refers to 2D boxplot from previous step
p + geom_point(data = iris, 
               aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, group = Species, color = Species),
               inherit.aes = F, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image: 2D boxplot with scatterplot overlay]